# Typescript type inference with union of tuple types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given the following types

```js
type Tool = 'network_query' | 'cluster'
type Network = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'

class QueryOneParams {...}
class QueryTwoParams {...}
class QueryThreeParams {...}
class ClusterParams {...}
```

I'm trying to define a mapping between combinations of `Tool` and `Network` so that I could write something like this:

```js
const queryParamsLookup = {
    'one': QueryOneParams,
    'two': QueryTwoParams,
    'three': QueryThreeParams
}

type Job<Tool, Network> = {
    id: string,
    params: JobParams<Tool, Network>
}
```

where

- `JobParams<'network_query', 'one'>` resolves to `QueryOneParams`
- `JobParams<'network_query', 'two'>` resolves to `QueryTwoParams`
- `JobParams<'network_query', 'three'>` resolves to `QueryThreeParams`
- `JobParams<'cluster'>` resolves to `ClusterParams`
- `JobParams<'cluster', 'one'>`, `JobParams<'cluster', 'two'>` and `JobParams<'cluster', 'three'>` are invalid

That would require me to somehow define that the second generic parameter `'one' | 'two' | 'three'` is only used and required, if the first parameter is `'network_query'`. Afaik, Typescript does not support optionally defined generic parameters based on the type of another parameter.

Is that correct? I'd love to be wrong here :)

As an alternative, I have defined a helper type like so:

```js
type NetworkQueryJobType = {
    [N in keyof typeof queryParamsLookup]: ['network_query', N]
}[keyof typeof queryParamsLookup]
// ['network_query', 'one'] | ['network_query', 'two'] | ['network_query', 'three']

type JobType = NetworkQueryJobType | ['cluster']
// ['network_query', 'one'] | ['network_query', 'two'] | ['network_query', 'three'] | ['cluster']
```

and changed the definition of `Job` to

```js
type Job<JobType> = {
    id: string,
    params: JobParams<JobType>
}
```

with this approach, I'm having trouble getting type inference to work properly in the mapper type `JobParams`:

```js
type JobParams<T extends JobType> = T extends ['network_query', infer N] ?
typeof queryParamsLookup[N] // Error: N is not compatible with 'one' | 'two' | 'three'
: ClusterParams
```

I can work around the type inference issue with:

```js
type JobParams<T extends JobType> = T extends ['network_query', infer N] ?
N extends Network ?
    typeof queryParamsLookup[N] // No error
    : ClusterParams
: ClusterParams
```

All of that however still leaves me with poor autocomplete performance when typing, for example:

```js
const params: JobParams<['
```

VSCode will not suggest `'cluster' | 'network_query'`

All in all, I feel like fighting a losing battle here. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9nANlAvFA5AOwsA7nAJwGsB9ARwFcICR0oAfDAY0QoGdhr0AoUSKAHI58xVBjjY6jdHjhSMwABYEIEHtxYBDNmygBFKjQDy2AAqaCmgLa6A3gF8NibboPUQMfOcs2oDpy76hh7Kqt7Wdo5aOlAAwqwc1OG+-hoSHFCU7slsADIIRBRgYrbcUOXikgBcQe4mEDkANGUVMvjoNW40nnBNLeUyoWqdwTBDOdyOvODQQrLEXSAAUnAARjAzJf1QANoCUACWmFBEECBwAGZQfBCXmcE5+XCFYAC6NTtYwoSkWTTojUEr0mO1O5yuNzufxAjwKRWBAHoEbsvvNfsEAZU1K8GCjsGjyBjAW05DjGJ98SJ0e5MYMVNjuNN+Ct1ps0HMqYsWRt+OT0Cx2JwCOhgUzoCycgAeGBQCAAD04mAAJrpuTMAHxiGXyxUqvHfYiEmmAo4XahAqAAfm4+x1EGVug5Pyt20hV2hsOeRT2OKRgjgsoIBEI2xq8UFSQsEW4YYSQom3D9NygLOlCEQgKdxE1aFKfoqhyVNQ4BCOAHNmvmKmAozYahLa2w00hMwaiOrE8ipsnU2rIDm-NsDkWoCXy80CzWfGx62spX2IB3HEA)

Comment: Aren't you using type `QueryOneParams` as an expression in `queryParamsLookup`?

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right! My intention was to abstract away some of my implementation detail. In reality, `QueryOneParams` and friends are classes. I'll change it in the question. Thank's for catching this :)

Comment: I've added a playground link for you (it's too long to fit in a comment). Your `Job` type is erroring. Please fix it and update the link in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **generic parameter defaults** and a neutral type, such as `null` to match the provided behavior.

I have made some assumptions about your code, please correct me if there is something I interpreted incorrectly.

Firstly, `queryParamsLookup` is a type `QueryParamsLookup`:

```
type QueryParamsLookup = {
    'one': QueryOneParams,
    'two': QueryTwoParams,
    'three': QueryThreeParams
}
```

defining the object as it is defined in the question will resolve the types to the types of provided class constructors, which is probably not what was intended as that would be quite rare.

The `JobParams` type can then be defined as:

```
type JobParams<T extends Tool, N extends T extends "network_query" ? Network : null = T extends "network_query" ? Network : null> =
    N extends Network ? QueryParamsLookup[N] : ClusterParams
```

Which would fulfill the following requirements:

```
// valid cases
const one: JobParams<"network_query", "one"> = new QueryOneParams()
const two: JobParams<"network_query", "two"> = new QueryTwoParams()
const three: JobParams<"network_query", "three"> = new QueryThreeParams()
const cluster: JobParams<"cluster"> = new ClusterParams()

// invalid cases
const inv1: JobParams<"cluster", "one"> = new QueryOneParams()
const inv2: JobParams<"cluster", "two"> = new QueryTwoParams()
const inv3: JobParams<"cluster", "three"> = new QueryThreeParams()
```

This definition of `JobParams` is pessimistic when a union is provided as its first argument, meaning it will treat the union as if it was not `network_query`. This behaviour can be inverted by flipping the ternary operators.

A link to a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2&ssl=1&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=27#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9nANlAvFA5AOwsA7nAJwGsB9ARwFcICR0oAfDAY0QoGdhr0AoUSKAHI58xVBjjY6jdHjhSMwABYEIEHtxYBDNmygBFKjQDy2AAqaCmgLa6A3tyiOoYCgCNEASyZQJ0NACJ-bgBfDURtXQNqEBh8c0sbKFsnKAcnF3cvKFkxQJCwiP1DGOVVeOs7NMcMz28lFT8oPNCtHSgAYVYOanLE+xSarJZ2TgJcoNDecGgoml62ABkEIgowMX6ndF90AC4i6JMIeYAaKoV8Xf2aWLgTs5lStT3Zkob5-Kn+ACk4V3mAHhgUAgAA9OJgACa6eBIY6CYFgiCQ6EI8FQprYWTEcjFfxQAD8gmEhCIUD2mAoiGQaCBoLRun8mJEpEo0TxhKEWNJ5MpiAAfKgzgJUUj0ZzmQSriB5ks4CswABtAQAXTJHS6o3e3AA9NqoAA3TSeCFQJjaCBsDQSDg+bB7H5-CwVf6M4nY1k0fxw-y+fwCtDYXBSw7zAAUAEorZgbbJ7b8Aa6uTi2d7ZH6xIGpTcw5GmNbgNlHnHHQk2C6mSTk57U490wGIEGXjBHjmozbht0CMWEx3RnWoJnOiMek6bBHuDq9R5MIbjabzZa89GC9P9QBGbujsv+XvUL1NX3+gcN4NmLfjpc21cAJk3pZdu4I+-8aaPmabcXPufzUFXAGY72dHcNT3GsGn7d9imbN4vyAA) with the solution.

While this is perfectly possible to do with a tuple generic as well, it is at quite excessive in my opinion and not very intuitive.

Comment: Looks good. Two open questions on my part:
- Is there some way to encapsulate the conditions in `JobParams`, so that I can use them in the `Job` type from my question without having to type them out twice? - `JobParams<'network_query'>` is now also a valid definition (maps to `QueryOneParams | QueryTwoParams | QueryThreeParams`), this is unexpected but actually quite convenient. However, is there a way to have `JobParams<'network_query'>` raise an error, because the second parameter is missing?

Comment: Question #1: I suppose a type alias might help but that is probably pushing the type system beyond its limits. I couldn't find a way to make that work in the current version.

Comment: Question #2: Yes there definitely is a way to do that, fallback to `never` when only `"network_query"` is the first parameter, like so: `type JobParams<T extends Tool, N extends T extends "network_query" ? Network : null = T extends "network_query" ? never : null> = N extends Network ? QueryParamsLookup[N] : ClusterParams`

Comment: Question #2 [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9nANlAvFA5AOwsA7nAJwGsB9ARwFcICR0oAfDAY0QoGdhr0AoUSKAHI58xVBjjY6jdHjhSMwABYEIEHtxYBDNmygBFKjQDy2AAqaCmgLa6A3tyiOoYCgCNEASyZQJ0NACJ-bgBfDURtXQNqEBh8c0sbKFsnKAcnF3cvKFkxQJCwiP1DGOVVeOs7NMcMz28lFT8oPNCtHSgAYVYOanLE+xSarJZ2TgJcoNDecGgoml62ABkEIgowMX6ndF90AC4i6JMIeYAaKoV8Xf2aWLgTs5lStT3Zkob5-Kn+ACk4V3mAHhgUAgAA9OJgACa6eBIY6CYFgiCQ6EI8FQprYWTEcjFfxQAD8gmEhCIUD2mAoiGQaCBoLRun8mJEpEo0TxhOwADdqGSoBSqQA+VBnASopHooRY0mEl7zJZwFZgADaAgAurzOiMehYKkA), unfortunately quite stripped down, since there is a comment char limit

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for all the effort and very good explanations :)